# btoa base64 из объекта File js

Tags: javascript, base64, blob

Я загружаю файл в формате через input file и могу получить к нему доступ через event.target.files[0].
Как мне объект файла превратить в blob, чтобы преобразовать его в base64 (например через btoa) средствами js?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="file" type="file"/>

<script>
document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change',event=>{
  const f = event.target.files[0];
  if(f){
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = ()=>{
      const fbase64 = fr.result; //файл в base64
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
});
</script>
```